# Incluir información en el index.html desde un arreglo con Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

Inicié un proyecto nuevo en Angular con el CLI. El index tiene esta estructura

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="viewport"    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Necesito agregar una `<meta>` que tenga varios elementos para el posicionamiento SEO, pero quiero controlarlo fuera del template

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ keywords.join() }}">
```

Quiero agregar esta línea de código y que sea más fácil administrarla e interpolarla en el HTML

```
const keywords: [] = ['foo', 'bar', 'poo']
```

Sin embargo no se donde ponerla para que el `index.html` lo reconozca.
Estuve pensando ponerlo en el `app.component.ts` pero no tiene relación con el index, si no con su propio componente.
¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: ¿hay algún motivo por el que la respuesta no se marca como resuelta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar el [Meta Service de Angular](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) e inyectarlo en el constructor. Puedes hacerlo en tu componente principal o en cualquiera y así personalizar los meta en cada componente.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private meta: Meta) {
    const keywords: string[] = ['foo', 'bar', 'poo']
    this.meta.addTag({ name: 'keywords', content: keywords.join(',') });
  }
}
```

Con MetaService puedes obtenerlos, actualizarlos, eliminarlos o añadirlos como verás en la documentación.

replico el mismo código en stackblitz para que lo veas funcionando, si te fijas en el codigo fuente añade los meta en el  sin que toques nada de tu HTML:
https://angular-metas.stackblitz.io

Comment: Agrego eso al app.component como lo interpolo en el HTML? Me podrías apoyar con un ejemplo?

Comment: Es suficiente con el código que te indico, el meta service de angular añade los meta al HTML. Si lo añades en tu componente principal (AppComponent) lo tendrás en el HTML después del render del DOM. No necesitas hacer nada en tu HTML.Si quieres personalizarlo por componente también funciona igual.